How to select the Checkboxes when there are set of both Enable and Disabled checkboxes katalon studio
How to select the Checkboxes when there are set of both Enable and Disabled checkboxes
my expected the checkbox can be check when the first checkbox is disabled can someone tell me how to fix? because iam already tried many option but still error and cannot click the checkbox above the disabled check box
